# Difference between DS1307 and IN1307N, I am using RTClib for making rtc module using IN1307N getting RTC is not running

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
// for Zero, output on USB Serial console, remove line below if using programming port to program the Zero!
#define Serial SerialUSB
#endif

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

void setup () {


#ifndef ESP8266
while (!Serial); // for Leonardo/Micro/Zero
#endif

Serial.begin(9600);
if (! rtc.begin()) {
Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
while (1);
}

if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
// following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
// This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
// January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
// rtc.adjust(DateTime(2014, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0));
}
}

void loop () {
DateTime now = rtc.now();

Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
Serial.print('/');
Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
Serial.print('/');
Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
Serial.print(" (");
Serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
Serial.print(") ");
Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
Serial.print(':');
Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
Serial.print(':');
Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
Serial.println();

Serial.print(" since midnight 1/1/1970 = ");
Serial.print(now.unixtime());
Serial.print("s = ");
Serial.print(now.unixtime() / 86400L);
Serial.println("d");

// calculate a date which is 7 days and 30 seconds into the future
DateTime future (now + TimeSpan(7,12,30,6));

Serial.print(" now + 7d + 30s: ");
Serial.print(future.year(), DEC);
Serial.print('/');
Serial.print(future.month(), DEC);
Serial.print('/');
Serial.print(future.day(), DEC);
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print(future.hour(), DEC);
Serial.print(':');
Serial.print(future.minute(), DEC);
Serial.print(':');
Serial.print(future.second(), DEC);
Serial.println();

Serial.println();
delay(3000);
}
```

[image]

If i use 57600 i'll get random symbols in one line 1 line.
I have connected PIN5 IN1307N to A4, PIN4 IN1307N to A5

[image]

Comment: What about pull-ups on SDA/SCL?

Comment: yup applied. 10k to vcc

Comment: Maybe try to use 4k7 (or two 10k in parallel) and shorter wires but it's a wild guess. And you can try [I2C scanner](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner) if RTC is even found. BTW value 165 is not so random as you think. It's 0xF*10 + 0xF e.g. 0xFF to BCD code.

Comment: Scanning...
No I2C devices found

Comment: Check your wiring: `A4` = `SDA` -> `PIN5`,  `A5` = `SCL` -> `PIN6` (`PIN4` is `GND` terminal)

Comment: yup thats connected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Following this circuitry solved my issue but still i've not understand the difference between DS1307 and IN1307N.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. Just different factory making the chip.